# Using Selenium and Java How to ignore part of an element in xpath

Tags: java, selenium

I have the method below:

```
protected String getCertID() {
    String certIDKey = "certID";
    TestAction action = new TestAction(ActionType.SET_ELEMENT_TEXT,springContext);

    action.setIdentifierType("xpath");
    action.setIdentifierValue("//h1[contains(@data-id,'header_title')]");
    action.setValue(certIDKey);

    action.perform(driverFactory,testContext);

    log.info("CertID: " + testContext.getVariable(certIDKey));
    return testContext.getVariable(certIDKey);
}
```

Output of this method : 21/2/467092- Saved

I require the method to return only: 21/2/467092 and ignore the - Saved part of element returned

Answer (score 1):

If `h1` contain child elements, e.g. some `span` elements, and the exact text you want to get placed in some child element, like:

```
<h1 data-id="header_title">
    <span id="date">21/2/467092</span>
    <span>- Saved</span>
</h1>
```

you can use

```
"//h1[contains(@data-id,'header_title')]/span[1]"
```

or

```
"//h1[contains(@data-id,'header_title')]/span[@id='date']"
```

Otherwise, for case:

```
<h1 data-id="header_title">21/2/467092- Saved</h1>
```

or

```
<h1 data-id="header_title">
    21/2/467092
    <span>- Saved</span>
</h1>
```

you can only adjust the result text of `h1`

```
...
String roughText = testContext.getVariable(certIDKey);
return roughText.split("-")[0].trim();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have found: //*[@id="formHeaderTitle_0"]/text() seems to find the correct part I need but running this in the method fails the test. This line suggested above  "//h1[contains(@data-id,'header_title')]/span[1]" just returns the part I do not need and this line above is not found //h1[contains(@data-id,'header_title')]/span[@id='date']

Comment: Try just  `//*[@id="formHeaderTitle_0"]`, without `/text()`.

Comment: NULL Returned "text" must be the certificate reference number

Comment: Sorry, `/span[1]` and `/span[@id='date']` are just examples, based on my assumption of how your page may look, since, I cannot see the real HTML page source.

Comment: Also, I see something happens behind the code example you've provided. It's unclear what is `testContext`. I see your action performed on it, then you get the variable. But I cannot see what selenium code executed. I assume you invoke `getText()` method on some WebElement, but no details.

Comment: testContext is a method where variable strings are saved such as certificate ID Case ID etc, its not the easiest framework to work with

Answer (score 0):

If the `"- Saved"` is constant there, you can just replace it with `""` :

```
protected String getCertID() {
  String certIDKey = "certID";
  TestAction action = new TestAction(ActionType.SET_ELEMENT_TEXT,springContext);

  action.setIdentifierType("xpath");
  action.setIdentifierValue("//h1[contains(@data-id,'header_title')]");
  action.setValue(certIDKey);

  action.perform(driverFactory,testContext);

  log.info("CertID: " + testContext.getVariable(certIDKey));
return testContext.getVariable(certIDKey).replace("- Saved", "");
}
```

Comment: I have tried to use this but when using this I see error "action.setValue(certIDKey); unreachable statement"

Comment: try to copy and past the updated code

Comment: I have updated the post above thank you         action.setValue(certIDKey); = unreachable statement

Comment: just  replace you return statement by mine ,dont write 2 return inside your method , and it will be run , java prevent you from wrinting a code that cannot be executed by the jvm " unreachable code "

Comment: Of course yes I have changed it and the returned value still contains -saved I have edited the above code as refence thank you